# Using regex to match variations of a string

Tags: regex

I have a list of OS names that I am trying to normalize, and I'm using regex to try to match the string. Here are the variations of the string:

```
microsoft windows 2016
win2016
win2012
windows 2012
windows server 2012
windows server 2008 r2
windows server 2008
windows 2019
windows 2012 r2 std
win2003
windows server 2003
windows 2003
```

[Here is my attempt](https://regex101.com/r/vjFQFw/1/) (I'm very bad at regex):

```
(windows.*server|((win|windows)*.(2003|2008|2012|2016|2019)))
```

According to the link above, it is matching `n2016` and not `win2016`, which could be problematic as the list will consist of other operating system names. Are there any improvements that could increase the accuracy of the match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the pattern you tried, to match all the windows variations without matching `n2016` instead of `win2016` you could use make use of word boundaries, an alternation and a character class to shorten the list of numbers.

You don't need any capture groups.

```
\bwin(?:dows)?(?:\s+server)?(?:\s*(?:200[38]|201[269]))?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bwin` A word boundary to prevent the word being part of a longer word, and match *win*
- `(?:dows)?` Optionally match *dows*
- `(?:\s+server)?` Optionally match 1+ whitespace chars and *server*
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
  - `(?:200[38]|201[269])` Match either 2003 2008 2012 2016 2019
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/57V4hM/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
microsoft\s+windows\s+2016|win(?:20(?:03|1[26])|dows\s+(?:20(?:03|1(?:2(?:\s+r2\s+std)?|9))|server\s+20(?:0(?:3|8(?:\s+r2)?)|12)))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7351La/1)

*Details*

- `microsoft\s+windows\s+2016` - `microsoft windows 2016`
- `|` - or
- `win` - `win`
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `20(?:03|1[26])` - `20`, then `03` or `1` followed with `2` or `6`
  - `|` - or
  - `dows` - `dows`
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

    - `20(?:03|1(?:2(?:\s+r2\s+std)?|9))` - `20` followed with either `03` or `1` that is followed with either `2` that is followed with 1+ whitespaces and `r2`, whitespaces, `std` (optionally) or `9`
    - `|` - or
    - `server\s+20` - `server`, 1+ whitespaces, `20`
    - `(?:` - start of another group

      - `0(?:3|8(?:\s+r2)?)` - `0`, then `3` or `8` followed with an optional substring of 1+ whitespaces and `r2`
      - `|` - or
      - `12` - `12`
    - `)` - end of the group
  - `)` - end of the group
- `)` - end of the group

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
/^((?:microsoft )?(?:win|windows)(?:[ ]| server )?(?:2003|2008|2012|2019|2016)(?: r2)?(?: std)?)$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/67GhF5/1)

Comment: This looks good and maintainable. Could you add `windows server` to your list with a match? Otherwise, it's almost perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an exact collection of strings, just create a dictionary to map them as you please or a list to test membership!

```py
# KeyError for missing keys; call .get() to get None instead
normalized_version = version_dict[test_input.strip().lower()]
```

```py
versions = ['microsoft windows 2016', 'win2016', 'win2012', 'windows 2012', 'windows server 2012', 'windows server 2008 r2', 'windows server 2008', 'windows 2019', 'windows 2012 r2 std', 'win2003', 'windows server 2003', 'windows 2003']
if test_input.strip().lower() in versions:
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this just a subset of the possibilities. The SOO is a mess and I can expect that there will be other variations.